# How to Sendmail Using NodeMailer (Not SMTP) With Promise (Bluebird)?

Tags: javascript, express, promise, bluebird, nodemailer

How to sendmail using nodemailer + bluebird (Promise). I successfully send to Email, but not response for it (in the page it still loading and doesn't response anything, but it succeeds in sending to email).

This is file js :

```
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        sendmail: true,
        newline: "windows",
        logger: false
      }),
      message = {
        from: "noreply@from.com",
        to: variabletoemail,
        subject: variablesubject,
        html: variablesendhtml
      };
    transporter.sendMail(message, (error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        resolve("0"); //can't call
      } else {
        resolve("1"); //can't call
      }
    });
  });
```

Does anyone know my problem above. Please help me

Comment: according to *[documentation](https://nodemailer.com/about/)* `transporter.sendMail` returns a Promise, and doesn't take a callback function - so you won't need the `new promise` just return `transporter.sendMail`

Comment: Please write your code that calls this code

Comment: @RaminRezazadeh - what possible use is that? the problem is the OP is not using nodemailer correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on documentation, send mail return promise and you can not use it with callback passing.
You can use it with await and use `try catch` to resolve or reject your promise.

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        sendmail: true,
        newline: "windows",
        logger: false
      }),
      message = {
        from: "noreply@from.com",
        to: variabletoemail,
        subject: variablesubject,
        html: variablesendhtml
      };
    try{
      await transporter.sendMail(message);
      resolve("1")
    }catch(e){
      reject(e)
    }
  });
```

or without `try catch`:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            sendmail: true,
            newline: "windows",
            logger: false
          }),
          message = {
            from: "noreply@from.com",
            to: variabletoemail,
            subject: variablesubject,
            html: variablesendhtml
          };
          transporter.sendMail(message).then(()=>{
           resolve("1")
          }).catch((e) => {
           reject(e)
          });
      });
```

Comment: hey thanks, I tried using try catch and it was successful.